# Cloned Laravel project and install composer and npm then also give me error 500 page not found

Tags: php, laravel

I created project and push it to github
Now I clone it into another pc

What i have done is

```
> composer install
> npm install

//also import the same database in sql
```

now when I open project link in browser it's showing me error of page not found **500**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create copy .env.example to .env file

```
> copy .env.example .env

> php artisan key:generate
```

then goto your .env file and change database details
this might work for you

Comment: I just found it before you answered but it's the right solution

Answer (score 1):

try `php artisan serve` and then `localhost:3000` on browser